# convert long dataframe to single line dataframe with enumerating the column names

Tags: pandas, dataframe

have a df that looks like this:

```
data = \
[{'len_overlap': 2, 'prox': 1.0, 'freq_sum_w': 0.03962264150943396},
{'len_overlap': 22, 'prox': np.nan, 'freq_sum_w': 0.0311111962264150943396}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | len_overlap | prox | freq_sum_w |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 0.0396226 |
| 1 | 22 | nan | 0.0311112 |

I want to make it one row data frame, so far I have this:

```
 pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(df.values)], columns=sum([[f'{x}_{n}' for x in df.columns] for n in range(df.shape[0])], []))
```

|  | len_overlap_0 | prox_0 | freq_sum_w_0 | len_overlap_1 | prox_1 | freq_sum_w_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 0.0396226 | 22 | nan | 0.0311112 |

This is what I want (the ints convert to floats, don't know why, but that's not a problem) but I'm wondering if there is a nicer, more Pandas way for doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line but more complex:

```
>>> df.unstack() \
      .to_frame() \
      .set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df.index.astype(str)])
                              .sortlevel(1)[0]
                              .to_flat_index()
                              .map('_'.join)) \
      .transpose()

   freq_sum_w_0  len_overlap_0  prox_0  freq_sum_w_1  len_overlap_1    prox_1
0           2.0           22.0     1.0           NaN       0.039623  0.031111
```

IMHO, I think the "more Pandas way" is to use a `MultiIndex`:

```
>>> df.stack().to_frame().transpose()

            0                           1
  len_overlap prox freq_sum_w len_overlap freq_sum_w
0         2.0  1.0   0.039623        22.0   0.031111
```

or better (like `pd.melt`):

```
>>> df.stack()
0  len_overlap     2.000000
   prox            1.000000
   freq_sum_w      0.039623
1  len_overlap    22.000000
   freq_sum_w      0.031111
```

Answer (score 2):

Try via `unstack()`,`to_frame()` and `Transpose(T)` attribute:

```
out=df.unstack().to_frame().T
```

Finally:

```
out.columns=out.columns.map(lambda x:'_'.join(map(str,x)))
```

output of `out`:

```
    len_overlap_0   len_overlap_1   prox_0  prox_1  freq_sum_w_0    freq_sum_w_1
0   2.0             22.0            1.0     NaN     0.039623        0.031111
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
df_out = df.unstack()
df_out = df_out.sort_index(level=1)
df_out.index = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.index]
df_out.to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
   freq_sum_w_0  len_overlap_0  prox_0  freq_sum_w_1  len_overlap_1  prox_1
0      0.039623            2.0     1.0      0.031111           22.0     NaN
```